# CEF and dragging a captionless window with WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, chromium-embedded

I am developing a C++ application displaying an MFC window without a caption (the top window bar), with a CEF control inside it. I would like the user to be able to click any area of the window and drag it as if the caption was being dragged.

The usual solution seems to be simulating a caption click, either by posting WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN with wparam HTCAPTION, or intercepting WM_NCHITTEST and returning HTCAPTION. I tested both solutions - they work great as long as I click a non-CEF area of the window. Clicking a CEF area is detectable in my MFC code, but I am unable to drag the window.

I have a hunch CEF (or chromium inside it) is intercepting some of my NC* messages; or posting their own versions. However, I don't know how to debug it or prevent it.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this, or any alternative solutions?

Comment: You might want to try using Spy++ to trap messages for the window in question.  that would, at a minimum, tell you what is getting through to the window.

Comment: I run into the same question, any idea?

Comment: No, I didn't manage to make any progress and we abandoned the feature :(